Random ESP-NOW sending failure, fixed by wrapping paper/hand, but why?
I am working on wireless data transmission between three ESP32 modules (ESP32-WROOM-32D with PCB antenna) by ESP-NOW (a derivative of WIFI). They are within 0.5 meter apart and are blocked by some aluminum/plastic frames. There is no obvious EM interference nearby. Both modules are powered by USB with no peripheral attached. My code is almost identical to the Arduino tutorial (default 1M data rate, on WIFI channel 3, no encryption, compiled with ESP32-arduino 2.0.4).
In most of the time, the projects work fine. However, at some random point, board-A become incapable of sending data (reporting failures in callbacks, as OnDataSent(...) in the tutorial) to either board-B and C. Yet, it is perfectly capable of receiving data over ESP-NOW. Everything works between board-B and C.
Rebooting board-A or letting it cool for a few hours didn't make a difference. I also tried to release possible static charges by touching its shield/ground by hand/metal bar but no luck. Magically, when I wrapped my hand over it, the transmission resumed. Alternatively, wrapping it in a few layers of paper also worked. Removing either wrap stop the sending (but not receiving) instantly.
The same magic happened on two of my boards so I guess it is not a random incident. But why?
